# Asking for Permissions in C# Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms, permissions

I am trying to ask for permissions to storage in order to store n access the json files containing my data. If access is denied then close the app. My issue is that the app isn't asking for the permissions

this is the main app code:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using TravelPack.Views;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using Xamarin.Essentials;


namespace TravelPack
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {

            CheckStoragePermission();

            //TravelPack.OOP.Lists.InitializeLists();
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
        }

        private async void CheckStoragePermission()
        {
            var status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.StorageRead>();
            if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
                status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.StorageRead>();

                if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
                {
                    CloseApp();
                }
            }
        }

        private void CloseApp()
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you added said permissions to the platform-specific locations, i.e., in the Android manifest and/or whatever iOS uses?

Comment: @SpaceBeeGaming No but since I am writing with xamari.forms I was hoping it wouldn't be necessary. I try to avoid platform-specific code in order to have easier updates when I finally launch. I will try it just to see if the issue continues. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

> My issue is that the app isn't asking for the permissions.

If your app targets Android 13 or higher and needs to access media files that other apps have created, you must request one or more of the following granular media permissions instead of the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission`:

Please follow the instrustions below:

1. Declare the permission in Android manifest file:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
```

2. Add the code above in your MainActivity.cs:

```
  protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
      base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

      Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
      global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);


      LoadApplication(new App());

      if (ActivityCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Android.Manifest.Permission.ReadMediaImages) != Android.Content.PM.Permission.Granted)
      {

          if ((int)Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt > 32)
          {

              AndroidX.Core.App.ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(
              Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.CurrentActivity, new string[] { Android.Manifest.Permission.ReadMediaImages }, 101);
          }

          else
          {
              AndroidX.Core.App.ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(
              Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.CurrentActivity, new string[] { Android.Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage }, 101);
          }

      }


  }
  public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
  {
      if (requestCode == 101)
      {
          if (grantResults.Length <= 0 || grantResults[0] != Permission.Granted)
          {
             System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
          }

      }

      Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

      base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
  }
```

Comment: I'll try but is there any way to write cross platform code to implement this?

Comment: @GaelPinto Thanks for the update, I think it's possible, you may request the permission in the main thread, here's a sample code for your reference:https://github.com/developmedev/DevelopMeTutorials/blob/master/DevelopMeTutorials/App.xaml.cs